# MEAN with TypeScript: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'socket.io'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I develop MEAN, with TypeScript (compiled with grunt - Using tsc v1.8.10)

```
$ npm install socket.io --save
SLMusic@1.0.0 /vagrant/mean
└─┬ socket.io@2.0.3 
  ├── socket.io-adapter@1.1.1 
  ├── socket.io-client@2.0.3 
  └─┬ socket.io-parser@3.1.2 
    └── isarray@2.0.1 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^0.3.8 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@0.3.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN mongoskin@1.4.13 requires a peer of mongodb@~1.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN SLMusic@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN SLMusic@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

in my code I did

```
import * as socketIo from "socket.io";
```

but when I run `grunt` I get:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'socket.io'.
```

I read a few similar question, so please do not mark as duplicate

I tried to

1. `npm cache clean`
2. `npm install socket.io -g`
3. delete directories from node_module
4. `npm install @types/socket.io --save`
5. `npm i --save @types/socket.io`
6. `sudo npm update npm -g`

BYPASS:

if I run `grunt --force` than I still get the error but the app is running

Answer (score 0):

Add line to `_all.d.ts`

`/// <reference path="../typings/socketio.d.ts" />`

NOTE: in my app.ts I have `/// <reference path="_all.d.ts" />`

I added file `sockeio.d.ts`

```
// Type definitions for socket.io 1.4.4
// Project: http://socket.io/
// Definitions by: PROGRE <https://github.com/progre>, Damian Connolly <https://github.com/divillysausages>, Florent Poujol <https://github.com/florentpoujol>, KentarouTakeda <https://github.com/KentarouTakeda>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped


declare module 'socket.io' {
    var server: SocketIOStatic;

    export = server;
}

interface SocketIOStatic {
    /**
     * Default Server constructor
     */
    (): SocketIO.Server;

    /**
     * Creates a new Server
     * @param srv The HTTP server that we're going to bind to
     * @param opts An optional parameters object
     */
    (srv: any, opts?: SocketIO.ServerOptions): SocketIO.Server;

    /**
     * Creates a new Server
     * @param port A port to bind to, as a number, or a string
     * @param An optional parameters object
     */
    (port: string|number, opts?: SocketIO.ServerOptions): SocketIO.Server;

    /**
     * Creates a new Server
     * @param A parameters object
     */
    (opts: SocketIO.ServerOptions): SocketIO.Server;

    /**
     * Backwards compatibility
     * @see io().listen()
     */
    listen: SocketIOStatic;
}

declare namespace SocketIO {

    interface Server {
        engine: { ws: any };

        /**
         * A dictionary of all the namespaces currently on this Server
         */
        nsps: {[namespace: string]: Namespace};

        /**
         * The default '/' Namespace
         */
        sockets: Namespace;

        /**
         * Sets the 'json' flag when emitting an event
         */
        json: Server;

        /**
         * Server request verification function, that checks for allowed origins
         * @param req The http.IncomingMessage request
         * @param fn The callback to be called. It should take one parameter, err,
         * which will be null if there was no problem, and one parameter, success,
         * of type boolean
         */
        checkRequest( req:any, fn:( err: any, success: boolean ) => void ):void;

        /**
         * Gets whether we're serving the client.js file or not
         * @default true
         */
        serveClient(): boolean;

        /**
         * Sets whether we're serving the client.js file or not
         * @param v True if we want to serve the file, false otherwise
         * @default true
         * @return This Server
         */
        serveClient( v: boolean ): Server;

        /**
         * Gets the client serving path
         * @default '/socket.io'
         */
        path(): string;

        /**
         * Sets the client serving path
         * @param v The path to serve the client file on
         * @default '/socket.io'
         * @return This Server
         */
        path( v: string ): Server;

        /**
         * Gets the adapter that we're going to use for handling rooms
         * @default typeof Adapter
         */
        adapter(): any;

        /**
         * Sets the adapter (class) that we're going to use for handling rooms
         * @param v The class for the adapter to create
         * @default typeof Adapter
         * @return This Server
         */
        adapter( v: any ): Server;

        /**
         * Gets the allowed origins for requests
         * @default "*:*"
         */
        origins(): string;

        /**
         * Sets the allowed origins for requests
         * @param v The allowed origins, in host:port form
         * @default "*:*"
         * return This Server
         */
        origins( v: string ): Server;

        /**
         * Attaches socket.io to a server
         * @param srv The http.Server that we want to attach to
         * @param opts An optional parameters object
         * @return This Server
         */
        attach( srv: any, opts?: ServerOptions ): Server;

        /**
         * Attaches socket.io to a port
         * @param port The port that we want to attach to
         * @param opts An optional parameters object
         * @return This Server
         */
        attach( port: number, opts?: ServerOptions ): Server;

        /**
         * @see attach( srv, opts )
         */
        listen( srv: any, opts?: ServerOptions ): Server;

        /**
         * @see attach( port, opts )
         */
        listen( port: number, opts?: ServerOptions ): Server;

        /**
         * Binds socket.io to an engine.io intsance
         * @param src The Engine.io (or compatible) server to bind to
         * @return This Server
         */
        bind( srv: any ): Server;

        /**
         * Called with each incoming connection
         * @param socket The Engine.io Socket
         * @return This Server
         */
        onconnection( socket: any ): Server;

        /**
         * Looks up/creates a Namespace
         * @param nsp The name of the NameSpace to look up/create. Should start
         * with a '/'
         * @return The Namespace
         */
        of( nsp: string ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Closes the server connection
         */
        close( fn ?: () => void ):void;

        /**
         * The event fired when we get a new connection
         * @param event The event being fired: 'connection'
         * @param listener A listener that should take one parameter of type Socket
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        on( event: 'connection', listener: ( socket: Socket ) => void ): Namespace;

        /**
         * @see on( 'connection', listener )
         */
        on( event: 'connect', listener: ( socket: Socket ) => void ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Base 'on' method to add a listener for an event
         * @param event The event that we want to add a listener for
         * @param listener The callback to call when we get the event. The parameters
         * for the callback depend on the event
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        on( event: string, listener: Function ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Targets a room when emitting to the default '/' Namespace
         * @param room The name of the room that we're targeting
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        to( room: string ): Namespace;

        /**
         * @see to( room )
         */
        in( room: string ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Registers a middleware function, which is a function that gets executed
         * for every incoming Socket, on the default '/' Namespace
         * @param fn The function to call when we get a new incoming socket. It should
         * take one parameter of type Socket, and one callback function to call to
         * execute the next middleware function. The callback can take one optional
         * parameter, err, if there was an error. Errors passed to middleware callbacks
         * are sent as special 'error' packets to clients
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        use( fn: ( socket:Socket, fn: ( err?: any ) => void ) =>void ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Emits an event to the default Namespace
         * @param event The event that we want to emit
         * @param args Any number of optional arguments to pass with the event. If the
         * last argument is a function, it will be called as an ack. The ack should
         * take whatever data was sent with the packet
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        emit( event: string, ...args: any[]): Namespace;

        /**
         * Sends a 'message' event
         * @see emit( event, ...args )
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        send( ...args: any[] ): Namespace;

        /**
         * @see send( ...args )
         */
        write( ...args: any[] ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Gets a list of clients
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        clients( ...args: any[] ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Sets the compress flag
         * @return The default '/' Namespace
         */
        compress( ...args: any[] ): Namespace;
    }

    /**
     * Options to pass to our server when creating it
     */
    interface ServerOptions {

        /**
         * The path to server the client file to
         * @default '/socket.io'
         */
        path?: string;

        /**
         * Should we serve the client file?
         * @default true
         */
        serveClient?: boolean;

        /**
         * The adapter to use for handling rooms. NOTE: this should be a class,
         * not an object
         * @default typeof Adapter
         */
        adapter?: Adapter;

        /**
         * Accepted origins
         * @default '*:*'
         */
        origins?: string;

        /**
         * How many milliseconds without a pong packed to consider the connection closed (engine.io)
         * @default 60000
         */
        pingTimeout?: number;

        /**
         * How many milliseconds before sending a new ping packet (keep-alive) (engine.io)
         * @default 25000
         */
        pingInterval?: number;

        /**
         * How many bytes or characters a message can be when polling, before closing the session
         * (to avoid Dos) (engine.io)
         * @default 10E7
         */
        maxHttpBufferSize?: number;

        /**
         * A function that receives a given handshake or upgrade request as its first parameter,
         * and can decide whether to continue or not. The second argument is a function that needs
         * to be called with the decided information: fn( err, success ), where success is a boolean
         * value where false means that the request is rejected, and err is an error code (engine.io)
         * @default null
         */
        allowRequest?: (request:any, callback: (err: number, success: boolean) => void) => void;

        /**
         * Transports to allow connections to (engine.io)
         * @default ['polling','websocket']
         */
        transports?: string[];

        /**
         * Whether to allow transport upgrades (engine.io)
         * @default true
         */
        allowUpgrades?: boolean;

        /**
         * parameters of the WebSocket permessage-deflate extension (see ws module).
         * Set to false to disable (engine.io)
         * @default true
         */
        perMessageDeflate?: Object|boolean;

        /**
         * Parameters of the http compression for the polling transports (see zlib).
         * Set to false to disable, or set an object with parameter "threshold:number"
         * to only compress data if the byte size is above this value (1024) (engine.io)
         * @default true|1024
         */
        httpCompression?: Object|boolean;

        /**
         * Name of the HTTP cookie that contains the client sid to send as part of
         * handshake response headers. Set to false to not send one (engine.io)
         * @default "io"
         */
        cookie?: string|boolean;
    }

    /**
     * The Namespace, sandboxed environments for sockets, each connection
     * to a Namespace requires a new Socket
     */
    interface Namespace extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {

        /**
         * The name of the NameSpace
         */
        name: string;

        /**
         * The controller Server for this Namespace
         */
        server: Server;

        /**
         * A dictionary of all the Sockets connected to this Namespace, where
         * the Socket ID is the key
         */
        sockets: { [id: string]: Socket };

        /**
         * A dictionary of all the Sockets connected to this Namespace, where
         * the Socket ID is the key
         */
        connected: { [id: string]: Socket };

        /**
         * The Adapter that we're using to handle dealing with rooms etc
         */
        adapter: Adapter;

        /**
         * Sets the 'json' flag when emitting an event
         */
        json: Namespace;

        /**
         * Registers a middleware function, which is a function that gets executed
         * for every incoming Socket
         * @param fn The function to call when we get a new incoming socket. It should
         * take one parameter of type Socket, and one callback function to call to
         * execute the next middleware function. The callback can take one optional
         * parameter, err, if there was an error. Errors passed to middleware callbacks
         * are sent as special 'error' packets to clients
         * @return This Namespace
         */
        use( fn: ( socket:Socket, fn: ( err?: any ) => void ) =>void ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Targets a room when emitting
         * @param room The name of the room that we're targeting
         * @return This Namespace
         */
        to( room: string ): Namespace;

        /**
         * @see to( room )
         */
        in( room: string ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Sends a 'message' event
         * @see emit( event, ...args )
         * @return This Namespace
         */
        send( ...args: any[] ): Namespace;

        /**
         * @see send( ...args )
         */
        write( ...args: any[] ): Namespace;

        /**
         * The event fired when we get a new connection
         * @param event The event being fired: 'connection'
         * @param listener A listener that should take one parameter of type Socket
         * @return This Namespace
         */
        on( event: 'connection', listener: ( socket: Socket ) => void ): this;

        /**
         * @see on( 'connection', listener )
         */
        on( event: 'connect', listener: ( socket: Socket ) => void ): this;

        /**
         * Base 'on' method to add a listener for an event
         * @param event The event that we want to add a listener for
         * @param listener The callback to call when we get the event. The parameters
         * for the callback depend on the event
         * @ This Namespace
         */
        on( event: string, listener: Function ): this;

        /**
         * Gets a list of clients.
         * @return This Namespace
         */
        clients( fn: Function ): Namespace;

        /**
         * Sets the compress flag.
         * @param compress If `true`, compresses the sending data
         * @return This Namespace
         */
        compress( compress: boolean ): Namespace;
    }

    /**
     * The socket, which handles our connection for a namespace. NOTE: while
     * we technically extend NodeJS.EventEmitter, we're not putting it here
     * as we have a problem with the emit() event (as it's overridden with a
     * different return)
     */
    interface Socket extends NodeJS.EventEmitter{

        /**
         * The namespace that this socket is for
         */
        nsp: Namespace;

        /**
         * The Server that our namespace is in
         */
        server: Server;

        /**
         * The Adapter that we use to handle our rooms
         */
        adapter: Adapter;

        /**
         * The unique ID for this Socket. Regenerated at every connection. This is
         * also the name of the room that the Socket automatically joins on connection
         */
        id: string;

        /**
         * The http.IncomingMessage request sent with the connection. Useful
         * for recovering headers etc
         */
        request: any;

        /**
         * The Client associated with this Socket
         */
        client: Client;

        /**
         * The underlying Engine.io Socket instance
         */
        conn: EngineSocket;

        /**
         * The list of rooms that this Socket is currently in, where
         * the ID the the room ID
         */
        rooms: { [id: string]: string };

        /**
         * Is the Socket currently connected?
         */
        connected: boolean;

        /**
         * Is the Socket currently disconnected?
         */
        disconnected: boolean;

        /**
         * The object used when negociating the handshake
         */
        handshake: {
            /**
             * The headers passed along with the request. e.g. 'host',
             * 'connection', 'accept', 'referer', 'cookie'
             */
            headers: any;

            /**
             * The current time, as a string
             */
            time: string;

            /**
             * The remote address of the connection request
             */
            address: string;

            /**
             * Is this a cross-domain request?
             */
            xdomain: boolean;

            /**
             * Is this a secure request?
             */
            secure: boolean;

            /**
             * The timestamp for when this was issued
             */
            issued: number;

            /**
             * The request url
             */
            url: string;

            /**
             * Any query string parameters in the request url
             */
            query: any;
        };

        /**
         * Sets the 'json' flag when emitting an event
         */
        json: Socket;

        /**
         * Sets the 'volatile' flag when emitting an event. Volatile messages are
         * messages that can be dropped because of network issues and the like. Use
         * for high-volume/real-time messages where you don't need to receive *all*
         * of them
         */
        volatile: Socket;

        /**
         * Sets the 'broadcast' flag when emitting an event. Broadcasting an event
         * will send it to all the other sockets in the namespace except for yourself
         */
        broadcast: Socket;

        /**
         * Targets a room when broadcasting
         * @param room The name of the room that we're targeting
         * @return This Socket
         */
        to( room: string ): Socket;

        /**
         * @see to( room )
         */
        in( room: string ): Socket;

        /**
         * Sends a 'message' event
         * @see emit( event, ...args )
         */
        send( ...args: any[] ): Socket;

        /**
         * @see send( ...args )
         */
        write( ...args: any[] ): Socket;

        /**
         * Joins a room. You can join multiple rooms, and by default, on connection,
         * you join a room with the same name as your ID
         * @param name The name of the room that we want to join
         * @param fn An optional callback to call when we've joined the room. It should
         * take an optional parameter, err, of a possible error
         * @return This Socket
         */
        join( name: string, fn?: ( err?: any ) => void ): Socket;

        /**
         * Leaves a room
         * @param name The name of the room to leave
         * @param fn An optional callback to call when we've left the room. It should
         * take on optional parameter, err, of a possible error
         */
        leave( name: string, fn?: Function ): Socket;

        /**
         * Leaves all the rooms that we've joined
         */
        leaveAll(): void;

        /**
         * Disconnects this Socket
         * @param close If true, also closes the underlying connection
         * @return This Socket
         */
        disconnect( close?: boolean ): Socket;

        /**
         * Returns all the callbacks for a particular event
         * @param event The event that we're looking for the callbacks of
         * @return An array of callback Functions, or an empty array if we don't have any
         */
        listeners( event: string ):Function[];

        /**
         * Sets the compress flag
         * @param compress If `true`, compresses the sending data
         * @return This Socket
         */
        compress( compress: boolean ): Socket;
    }

    /**
     * The interface used when dealing with rooms etc
     */
    interface Adapter extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {

        /**
         * The namespace that this adapter is for
         */
        nsp: Namespace;

        /**
         * A dictionary of all the rooms that we have in this namespace
         * The rooms are made of a `sockets` key which is the dictionary of sockets per ID
         */
        rooms: {[room: string]: {sockets: {[id: string]: boolean }, length: number }};

        /**
         * A dictionary of all the socket ids that we're dealing with, and all
         * the rooms that the socket is currently in
         */
        sids: {[id: string]: {[room: string]: boolean}};

        /**
         * Adds a socket to a room. If the room doesn't exist, it's created
         * @param id The ID of the socket to add
         * @param room The name of the room to add the socket to
         * @param callback An optional callback to call when the socket has been
         * added. It should take an optional parameter, error, if there was a problem
         */
        add( id: string, room: string, callback?: ( err?: any ) => void ): void;

        /**
         * Removes a socket from a room. If there are no more sockets in the room,
         * the room is deleted
         * @param id The ID of the socket that we're removing
         * @param room The name of the room to remove the socket from
         * @param callback An optional callback to call when the socket has been
         * removed. It should take on optional parameter, error, if there was a problem
         */
        del( id: string, room: string, callback?: ( err?: any ) => void ): void;

        /**
         * Removes a socket from all the rooms that it's joined
         * @param id The ID of the socket that we're removing
         */
        delAll( id: string ):void;

        /**
         * Broadcasts a packet
         * @param packet The packet to broadcast
         * @param opts Any options to send along:
         *  - rooms: An optional list of rooms to broadcast to. If empty, the packet is broadcast to all sockets
         *  - except: A list of Socket IDs to exclude
         *  - flags: Any flags that we want to send along ('json', 'volatile', 'broadcast')
         */
        broadcast( packet: any, opts: { rooms?: string[]; except?: string[]; flags?: {[flag: string]: boolean} } ):void;
    }

    /**
     * The client behind each socket (can have multiple sockets)
     */
    interface Client {
        /**
         * The Server that this client belongs to
         */
        server: Server;

        /**
         * The underlying Engine.io Socket instance
         */
        conn: EngineSocket;

        /**
         * The ID for this client. Regenerated at every connection
         */
        id: string;

        /**
         * The http.IncomingMessage request sent with the connection. Useful
         * for recovering headers etc
         */
        request: any;

        /**
         * The dictionary of sockets currently connect via this client (i.e. to different
         * namespaces) where the Socket ID is the key
         */
        sockets: {[id: string]: Socket};

        /**
         * A dictionary of all the namespaces for this client, with the Socket that
         * deals with that namespace
         */
        nsps: {[nsp: string]: Socket};
    }

    /**
     * A reference to the underlying engine.io Socket connection.
     */
    interface EngineSocket extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
        /**
         * The ID for this socket - matches Client.id
         */
        id: string;

        /**
         * The Engine.io Server for this socket
         */
        server: any;

        /**
         * The ready state for the client. Either 'opening', 'open', 'closing', or 'closed'
         */
        readyState: string;

        /**
         * The remote IP for this connection
         */
        remoteAddress: string;

        /**
         * whether the transport has been upgraded
         */
        upgraded: boolean;

        /**
         * (http.IncomingMessage): request that originated the Socket
         */
        request: any;

        /**
         * (Transport): transport reference
         */
        transport: any;
    }
}
```